# Integer division with decimals

Tags: c#

What's the proper way to do "integer" divisions with decimal types in C# ?

I.e.

```
 decimal a = 130, b  = 60;
 decimal res = a / b; //need to get 2.0, not 2.6666
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case I'd use the `Floor` function.

```
decimal res = Math.Floor(a / b);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
decimal a = 130, b = 60;

decimal res = Math.Floor(a/b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Decimal.Truncate(a / b);`

Decimal.Truncate() "rounds" towards zero, and is thus like Math.Floor() for positive numbers and Math.Ceiling() for negative numbers.

Comment: Upvoted for considering the case of negative numbers. Note that `Math.Truncate` and `Decimal.Truncate` are "the same". Similarly with `Math.Floor` and `Decimal.Floor` etc.